# Spring Batch + Spring API REST

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, spring-batch

I have set up a java batch project with spring batch that allows to persist the rows of a CSV in a table of a database.
I would have liked to know if it was possible with Spring API REST to trigger the Batch with a POST method that would join the necessary CSV.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that using a `Controller` with a `JobLauncher` and `Job`. The barebones of the controller would be like this

```
@RestController
public class MyController{
    // Usually given by Spring Batch
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    // Your Job
    private Job job;
    // Ctor
    public MyController(JobLauncher jobLauncher, Job job, ...){}

    @PostMapping("/")
    public String launchJob(...){
        ...
        // Create JobParameters and launch
        JobParameters jobparameters = new Job Parameters();
        jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
        ...
    }
}
```

SimpleJobLauncher, the implementation of JobLauncher, uses a synchronous executor by default, you'll probably want to change it to an Async one depending  of your requirements

Comment: So I managed to launch the job from a POST but how do I retrieve the CSV that I send in the method?

Comment: @Fosfor you can follow this [getting started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) to make a method to upload the file (MultipartFile has `transferTo` and `getBytes` which allow you to save the file). After that you can put the path of the file as string in the job parameters